# Returning a whole class of information inside a function

Tags: c++, pointers, encapsulation

so I've been working on a program where I have a class called CDistance, here it is,

```
class CDistance
{
private:
    int feet, inches;
public:
    CDistance();
    CDistance(int, int);
    void setDist();
    void printDist() const;
    CDistance add(const CDistance&) const;
};
```

part of what I need to do is to create an array of 5 of these objects, set the feet and inches on each one of them, and then add them together without changing the original variables. This is the function definition, as you can see, it's working with all constant members, so it's a matter of figuring out how to reference the variables, but most importantly, getting them back into a CDistance type to be returned. Should I create a new CDistance type within this function to work with the ref

```
CDistance CDistance::add(const CDistance&) const
{

}
```

That's where I've been stuck, I'm kind of confused about the whole pointers and encapsulation deal. I'm new to programming, and have learned that the hard way, but if someone could help me out with this, I would really appreciate it

Comment: _"I'm kind of confused about the whole pointers [...]"_ you're not using any pointers here. and that's a good thing. Is your code not working? Are you struggling with the implementation of `add`, or what?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can be confused about pointers in this example - you do not have any.  For your `add` function, are you expecting to add the passed distance data to the current distance data and return a new instance, or actually add it to the current instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `return` a local result instance from your function:

```
CDistance CDistance::add(const CDistance& other) const
{
    CDistance result(*this);

    // Calculate the result using result.feet, result.inches and 
    // other.feet, other.inches
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to declare a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator - the compiler will generate them for him.  The problem he appears to face is how to design his `add` function.

Comment: @ZacHowland I know well, I've made this up as a clarification for the OP. I mentioned returning a local instance.

Comment: But he doesn't need to define (and unless he needs to, really should not be defining) a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator.  He can return by copy with his code as is.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a new CDistance type within this function to work with the ref

Yes, you'll need a new object to modify and return:

```
CDistance add(const CDistance& other) const {
    CDistance result = *this;      // Copy this object
    result.feet += other.feet;     // Add the other object...
    result.inches += other.inches; // ... to the copy
    return result;                 // Return the copy
}
```

Note that this isn't complete; there's one deliberate error, and an unknown number of accidental errors, which you'll need to fix yourself.